# Bonjour data sending multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gamekit, bonjour

Does Bonjour allows one iOS device to send data or image to multiple iOS devices at a same time?

```
I am able to detect number of iOS devices over a wifi network. But the problem is coming in sending data or image to more than 1 iOS device at the same time.
```

Should i go for gamekit bluetooth approch for the above problem? Sample code for the question will be appreciated, and help is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think you should use Bluetooth to do the thing mentioned in your question.

Here are some of the samples. Please have a look:-

http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/

It may help you, Thanks!

Comment: Please look for the question, i am asking for sending data to multiple iOS devices at same time

Comment: Yeah i had replied for the same, what happen?

Comment: Nikhil mujhe ek sath ek msg 2 devices ko bhejna hai... pls help

Comment: I can only send msg to only one device at a time but i want to send it to multiple devices at a time

Comment: Yeah you can send one message to simultaneously two devices with this

Comment: What you need to do is get the peer id and send message to both the peer id which will be connected to Your primary device

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17804/discussion-between-nikhil-bansal-and-neha-mehta)